# How to add images to listview which user selects from a gridview of images. I think there is problem with array list animalNewList

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, gridview

"I am unable to add images to animalNewList on grid view click"

```
package com.example.a300287031.lec7_gridview;  


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView myGridView;
    //GridView myGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grdViewItems);
    ArrayList<Integer> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> animalDescList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> animalNewList = new ArrayList<>();
   Toast prevToast;
   ListView myList;

    public void addItems()
    {
        animalDescList.add("Eagle");
        animalList.add(R.drawable.eagle);
        animalDescList.add("Elephant");
        animalList.add(R.drawable.elephant);
        animalDescList.add("Panda");
        animalList.add(R.drawable.panda);
        animalDescList.add("Panther");
        animalList.add(R.drawable.panther);
        animalDescList.add("Polar");
        animalList.add(R.drawable.polar);
        animalDescList.add("Gorilla");
        animalList.add(R.drawable.gorilla);
    }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myList=findViewById(R.id.listViewSelectedItems);
        myGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grdViewItems);
        addItems();

        ImageAdapter myAdapter = new ImageAdapter(animalList,this);
        myGridView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        final ImageView imgLarge = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);MyCustomAdapter(animalNewList,this);






        myGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                imgLarge.setImageResource(animalList.get(position));

                if (prevToast != null)
                {
                    prevToast.cancel();
                }
                Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,animalDescList.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                myToast.show();
```

Over here I am trying to add images which are selected by the user to new arraylist.  I think they are adding to this:

```
                animalNewList.add(animalList.get(position));

                prevToast = myToast;


            }
        });
```

I am setting an adapter over here that should contain an arraylist which only has user selected images from gridview, but its not working.  If I try to add another list which already has images then its working.

```
        myList.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(animalNewList,this));


    }
}
```

Comment: `MyCustomAdapter(animalNewList,this)` This is not initialized and set to any list. Why?

Comment: just look at last line i have done over their .The thing is if i am giving animalList i.e another Arraylist which has already inserted data than it works fine